# Query Regarding topLinks in ../template/links.phtml

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, layout, template

Now I have a code

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
```

which gives me some set of menus like **Login**, **MyWishlist**,  **My Account**, **Checkout**, and **Mycart**. But, now i need to change the label of these above mentioned links. What should I do?

Comment: search the web. http://lmgtfy.com/?q=magento+top+links

Comment: Well thanks, but  I google'd it once but I am not getting how to change the label of those links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For login, logout and my account link you can create your own local.xml in your theme layout. And do something like below

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account(custom)</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account (custom)</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="top.links">

        </reference>
    </default>
    <customer_logged_in>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Log Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>My Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_in>
    <customer_logged_out>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Log In</label><url helper="customer/getLoginUrl"/><title>My Log In</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
        </reference>
    </customer_logged_out>
</layout>
```

The original code for this you can find in your layout customer.xml
For changing my cart and checkout link, you need to rewrite `Mage_Checkout_Block_Links` and then override its `addCartLink()` and `addCheckoutLink()` methods. 
And for changing wishlist link you can rewrite `Mage_Wishlist_Block_Links` and then override its `_createLabel` function.
Please remember, never change in core files always override them in your own module and for layout changes do them in your local.xml in your theme layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can just translate the label in your translation.